# Названия - число

Tags: названия

Скажите, пожалуйста, и ПРИВЕДИТЕ примеры, в чем заключается разница между индывидуальным, массовым и коллектИвным названиями

Answer (score 2):

Вы о нарицательных или собственных именах?

Для нарицательных: Человек, студент, корова - индивидуальное

Группа, компания, коллектив,семья-коллективное

Человечество, студенчество, народ, стадо, поголовье - массовое.